# Quitting some fullscreen apps leaves white lines on screen

Tags: macos, driver, gpu

When I make Eclipse (or ADT) full screen and then quit it using cmd+q, it causes glitches and white lines all over the screen which move when anything in the screen changes, like when I move the mouse pointer.

This problem doesn't go away even if I logout or sleep — I have to restart to solve it.

I tried running Xcode, iTunes and Messages in full screen and quitting them. Everything was okay with no problems, but the same problem occurs when talking on Skype video full screen and quitting.

I've read a lot about graphic driver problems in 10.9.2 but is this one of them or a hardware bug?

Comment: So this happens to all applications?

Comment: Show us the Console log at the time stamp in question to see the graphics mode switching.

Comment: @Rob no it doesn't, all apple applications that comes the new OS works fine. also I tried netbeans and every thing is fine.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I'm not sure where to get that, I think you mean copying text from the console app ?

Comment: Open your Console app in the Utility folder, scroll to the time stamp of the event then copy and paste some lines in here

Comment: sorry for being late I installed a fresh 10.9 and there was no problem at all, today I took the chance and upgraded back to 10.9.2 and installed jdownloader(java app) then full screen then cmd+q and the problem appeared again here is my log to the restart point http://pastebin.com/qjgccMK1

Comment: I tried it again after restart it didn't cause the problem but I got this in the log
http://pastebin.com/7ZqAGtu2